# Issue with Dropdown pulling data from SQL in Python Dash

Tags: python, sqlite, plotly-dash

I am having some issues with dropdowns and sql, i want to fill the dropdown with options from sql.

I’m not getting any errors, but all I am getting in the dropdown is just the name of the column in the database which is sale category.

This is the SQL elsewhere to pull my data:

```
def get_saletype_data():
    con = sqlite3.connect(str(DBFILE))
    saletypes = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT SaleCategory FROM SaleType", con)
    return saletypes
```

And this is what it produces if i print the output:

```
  SaleCategory
0          Cut
1   Highlights
2    Gel Nails
3         Perm
4   Extensions
5       Fringe
```

Here is the code in the app dealing with the sql:

```
salelist = get_saletype_data()
saletypedic = salelist.to_dict()
```

This is the code for the dropdown:

```
dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="sales-type-dropdown",
                    options=[{'label':saletype, 'value':saletype} for saletype in saletypedic],
                ),
```

Really appreciate any help on this, not sure why I am just getting the first option in the dropdown

Comment: What do you get when you print saletypedic ?
Also, whey are you converting salelist to dictionary before sending it to options if you are using a for loop to print label and value? you can directly use the list itself (ie. salelist)

Comment: {'SaleCategory': {0: 'Cut', 1: 'Highlights', 2: 'Gel Nails', 3: 'Perm', 4: 'Extensions', 5: 'Fringe'}} this is the result from printing saletypedic. Good point, I did get an erorr the first time but clearly it was something else. Even without using the dict, I still get the issue where It only shows SaleCategory and no other fields.

Comment: Try to print(type(salestypes)) It should be a list. Basically the what you want to get in your Dropdown component under options has to be a list of values that you want to display.

Comment: This is what I get when do that <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown component would need a `list` of values. 
So for example,

```
salelist = get_saletype_data()
salestypes = salelist['SaleCategory'].tolist()
```

Now in your dropdown use `salestypes`

```
dcc.Dropdown(
                id="sales-type-dropdown",
                options=[{'label':saletype, 'value':saletype} for saletype in saletypes],
            ),
```